# Using Bootstrapping to Compare the Mean of two samples - questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bootstrap

I have two large samples (around ~2 million each) of tweets with a very heavily skewed engagement distribution, and I want to compare their mean difference across several stratifications.

I have tried other tests but given the nature of the data, bootstrapping seemed to be the most reasonable choice to compare the means of the two samples across stratifications.

Would this be considered a valid approach? At the moment I am simply looking at the mean difference in the means of the two samples during bootstrapping.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Why not a t-test or a related ANOVA-type of analysis? Sure, the skewness can affect those, as it can affect bootstrapping.

Comment: Thank you! Mainly because at the moment I am running the comparison with 2 stratifications with multiple levels (each stratum has around 20 levels, so that creates a lot of resampling/comparisons) and bootstrapping looked more intuitive. But I am open to alternatives as well!

Comment: Perhaps you can explain this “stratification with multiple levels” in more detail. That sounds exactly like an ANOVA (perhaps two-way ANOVA, depending on the details).

Comment: Basically imagine I have variables like age and political leaning, each with 20 levels going from low to high (0 being lowest and 20 highest). I want to compare engagement only among tweets with the same level for age and political leaning, and obtain the values for the mean difference. I hope this explains the process a bit better!

Comment: ANOVA would be both powerful and *hugely* more efficient computationally than bootstrapping.  It also readily extends to more detailed regression models with covariates.